# How to restrict the start and the end thumb of the custom multisider

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-slider

So I have a component that is a multi-slider component, but the problem I am facing is that I want to restrict the 1st slider button to only move from 0 to 5 in this, and want to restrict the 2nd slider from 5 to 10, how could I achieve this? I have followed this link to build the slider

https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/5Lc4h5DWLwKlyy3yFxAE/src/multiSlider.html?p=stories

[image]

Thanks in advance